# Regular Expression to identify string containing dot(s), excluding dot(s) in double quotes

Tags: regex, contains

I want to match strings that contains dot(s) ., complexity is, it should not consider dot(s) that are enclosed in double quotes.

`<<8001_011._>>[01990.a|c01]+<<8001_011._>>[01990.b|c.01]` Match
`[01990.a|c01]+[01990|c.01]` Match
`"a" + "$.1" +  $1 + "b"` NOT Match, dot is enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this expression

```
([^."]*"[^"]*")*[^."]*\..*
```

Comment: This solved my issue
(<<[^\[]+>>)?\[[\w\$-\.,\s]+\|[\w\$-\.,\s]+\]